# Solution of non-linear differential equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I don't use Mathematica in general and I need it to compare with an other program. I want to solve a system of three differential and non linear equations. For this I use Dsolve. Everything goes wrong when I put the nonlinear term (exponential).

Here is my code:

```
equa = {x'[t] == z[t] - Exp[y[t]], 
y'[t] == z[t] - y[t], 
z'[t] == x[t] + y[t] - z[t], 
x[0] == 0, 
y[0] == 0, 
z[0] == 0};
slt = DSolve[equa, {x, y, z}, t]
Plot[{x[t] /. slt}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

And the errors are like this :

> DSolve::dsvar: 0.1 cannot be used as a variable.
>
> ReplaceAll::reps:{Dsolve[<<1>>]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid     dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing

Does someone know why the exponential term makes troubles ?

Thanks

Comment: try mathematica.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
s = NDSolve[equa, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[({x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s)], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't give me the write answer !

Comment: For this system certainly but for mine maple and python give a different and even a different behaviour from mathematica answer !

Comment: Then you should edit your question to include what you expect in plot form from maple and python.